# Sum of projection vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, projective-space

Let say i have an orthogonal base $B$ which is some base of $R^3$, and now i want to find the vector coordinates of $[1,2,3]$ by base $B$ using the sum of projection vectors.

1.Is there some formula for this calculation?
2. I would like to get the idea behind this question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The scalar projection of a vector $\vec v$ in the direction of another vector $\vec b$ is:
$$
v_b=\frac{\vec v \cdot \vec b}{||\vec b||}
$$

where ''$\cdot$'' is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

If you know the vectors $\{\vec b_i\}$  of the basis $B$ and $\vec v=[1,2,3]^T$ is your vector, these scalar projections are the component of $\vec v$ in the basis $B$.

Comment: Well i have the vectors of basis $B$ , so just to make it clear the components of  $\vec v$ in basis $B$ is $$
\frac{\vec v \cdot \vec b_{1}}{||\vec b_{1}||}
$$ and so ($b_{1},b_{2}...$)

Comment: Yes, it's correct.